# 'Context' object has no attribute 'view_layer' in Python Script

Tags: python, scripting, viewlayers

I'd like to run the script [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) 
but hit an error on the 2nd line:

```
view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'view_layer'
```

Autcompleting the bpy.context object does show there's no view_layer property...maybe the docs are outdated?

Comment: I would suggest to check which version of the API is used, as there is a possibility to search older as well as newer (beta version) API docs. If it's not for some special functionality change from 2.79, i would not see a reason to not update to 2.81.

Answer (score 1):

The manual page you've linked is for Blender 2.81 and is up-to-date. If you're using an older version of Blender you'll have to consult the matching version of the manual. The documentation of `bpy.types.Object` in Blender 2.79 can be found [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.Object.html).